# How do i stop the flicker in my scale animation?

Tags: android, xml, android-animation, flicker

I have a `PopupWindow` where i use `PopupWindow.setAnimationStyle();` to swop between two popupwindows. The swoping and the animation works. But when i scale the x value from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0 then it flickers.

for example, this will flicker:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="300" >
    <scale
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:fromXScale="1" android:toXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="1" android:toYScale="1" />
</set>
```

but this wont:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="300" >
    <scale
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:fromXScale="0.9" android:toXScale="0.1"
        android:fromYScale="1" android:toYScale="1" />
</set>
```

Why does this flicker and how do i make it not flicker?

This might be my device, but i have to make it not flicker on this device.
I have a samsung galaxy tab 2 10.1

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a delay attribute with minimum value,

```
android:startOffset="1"
```

it means animation will be faster which can reduce flickering. Like,

```
 <scale
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:fromXScale="0.9" android:toXScale="0.1"
        android:fromYScale="1" android:toYScale="1" 
        android:startOffset="1"/>
```

Also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748437/android-scale-animation-flickering) says, enable hardware acceleration, it did not worked for me, but I was able to solve the issue by adjusting delay and duration values. What is the value of your pivotY attribute?

Hope this helps, if you already solved the issue, kindly share the solution.